# Angular Material + TypeScript: Auto-complete + selecting option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I'm having an issue with my code at the moment, whereby if I create a new chip, it hits my label model and creates a name and ID.

However, when I type to select an option returned, if I click on the option, it returns an Object, rather than the label name.

Here's a screenshot of the UI, where the dropdown that appears for `md-autocomplete` returns the name, a new label is created with just the name displayed, but clicking on `hotel` returns `{"id":1,"name":"hotel"}`.

My problem is I want to return just the name and not sure where I need to make the change to do that.

**UI:**

[image]

**labels.html:**

```
<md-content layout="column">
    <md-chips ng-model="cont.vm.selectedLabels" md-autocomplete-snap md-require-match="false" 
        md-on-append="cont.createLabel($chip)">
      <md-autocomplete
          md-selected-item="cont.vm.selectedItem"
          md-search-text="searchText"
          md-items="item in cont.querySearch(searchText)"
          md-item-text="item.name"
          md-min-length="2"
          placeholder="Type to add a label">
        <span md-highlight-text="cont.vm.searchText" >{{item.name}}</span>
           <md-not-found>
             No matches found.
            </md-not-found>       
      </md-autocomplete>
      <md-chip-template>
        <span>
          <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong>
        </span>
      </md-chip-template>   
    </md-chips>
    <br />
    <p class="md-title">Existing Labels</p>
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item class="md-2-line label-option" ng-repeat="label in cont.vm.labels" layout="row"
          layout-wrap>
        <div class="md-item-text md-whiteframe-z1" flex>
          <h3>(NAME: {{label.name}}) (ID: {{label.id}})</h3>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-content>
```

**labelsController.ts:**

```
constructor(private $scope: common.IScope<LabelScope>, 
                private labelsService: ILabelsService){

                    super($scope);
                    this.vm.labels = this.loadLabels();
                    this.vm.selectedLabels = [];
                    this.vm.selectedItem = null;
                    this.vm.searchText = null;         
                    console.log($scope);           
            } 

            private loadLabels() {
                return this.labelsService.getLabels();
            }
            // Returns list of labels that already exists
            public querySearch (query: string) {
                var results = query ? this.loadLabels() : [];
                return results;
                console.log(results);
            }          
            // Returns name + ID on new chip created
            public createLabel($chip: string) {
                return {
                    name: $chip,
                    id: 4
                };                                               
            }
```

**labelsService.ts:**

```
 private mockLabels: Array<Label> = [
            new Label(1, 'hotel'),
            new Label(2, 'sport'),
            new Label(3, 'gaming'),
            new Label(4, 'apple'),
            new Label(5, 'retail')
        ];

        public getLabels() {
            return this.mockLabels;   
            console.log(this.mockLabels);         
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem a while ago. And the reason for this is that `md-on-append` function is called even if you select the item from the dropdown.

When you select an item from the dropdown, it actually returns following:

```
{
    name:{
           name:hotel,
           id:1
    },
    id:4
}
```

So you should change the code of `createLabel()` function a bit.

**JS:**

```
public createLabel($chip) {
    angular.forEach(this.vm.selectedLabels,function(element,index){
         if(element.name==$chip.name||element.name==$chip){
             this.vm.selectedLabels.splice(index,1);
         }
    })
    if($chip.id==undefined){
         return {
           name: $chip,
           id: 4
         };                                 
    }
    else{
        return $chip;
    }
```

Comment: Mate, you just saved me hours of work! I had no idea that ```md-on-append``` was called on selecting an element! Thank you very much!

I have one last question, however. How would I then enhance this code to prevent selecting 'hotel' more than once? Ie. How do I prevent user from using the tag again?

Comment: That's a mistake. It doesn't allow you to click and insert the same tag twice, because of the uniqueness of the id.

Comment: @RyanDrake Haha. I have spent hours on figuring out the same thing. I am glad i could save your time. And the answer to your second question, well I faced that problem as well. in `md-on-append` apply `angular.forEach` on the chips array and check if that element exists, then splice that element. and then return the same element. There is no other option.

Comment: Uh, what would that code look like? I'm so new to Typescript I'm not sure!

Comment: oh i forgot that you are using Typescript. Sorry boss, I have no knowledge of TypeScript. I thought you were using AngularJS. Anyways the logic is same. Apply a for loop on chips array and check if the $chip.name already exists then remove that element from the array and return the JSON.

Comment: I'm using Angular and Typescript! :) If you have an example that might work in JS, I can rewrite it in Typescript. That'd be legendary if you do bro :)